# gcc -W -Wall -O -pedantic -std=c99 vs clang with same options

Tags: c, gcc, osx-lion, clang

Trying to output a pointer's address in decimal form using the `%zu` conversion specifier. Runs okay as expected except that GCC warns

`format ‘%zu’ expects type ‘size_t’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int *’`

GCC options used are shown in the question. GCC still warns without any options set (other than `-std=c99`). clang however, does not issue any warnings at all with the same options. This is on OS X 10.7. Just curious why clang isn't issuing any warnings? Is GCC "better" than clang for debugging/compiling?

Comment: I don't think printf-format warnings are mandated by the standard. It's not a typesafe function, so ultimately the burden is on *you* to use it right.

Comment: I suppose that you know that the correct format specifier is `%p` and that even then a cast to `void*` is in order.

Comment: Yes I am aware of `%p` for pointers and then `void *` cast. However, I am outputting the values as decimals, not hex and also trying to understand why clang does not give any warnings at all. But as Mr. Cannon pointed out below, it could be a bug with `%zu` in clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be specific to the `z` size modifier in clang; you *do* get a warning with `%lu`, `%u`, `%hu`, etc.  (Even without any options)

Generally speaking, it has been my experience that clang has more useful warning messages than GCC does.  This is an exception to that experience.  I'll file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in a cast, but beware that if your code ever runs on a machine where size_t is not the same size as a pointer then it'll do the wrong thing. Probably fine though ...

```
printf ("%zu\n", (size_t)my_ptr);
```

Comment: nope, casting to size_t does not output the pointer addresses as expected. If, for example, incrementing a long pointer over an array of longs, then casting to size_t will show the addresses differing by one byte only. They are 8-bytes apart each sequentially on my machine .

Comment: @spinozagl it's true that "ptr+1 != ((size_t)ptr)+1", but that shouldn't affect printf. There's no pointer arithmetic going on there.

Comment: right, it shouldn't. Although this is not the main thrust of my inquiry here, it is quirky that iterating over an array of longs with a long pointer does as expected showing consecutive addresses 8-bytes apart (on my 64-bit machine), but as soon as I cast the pointer to size_t, the addresses are just 1-byte apart. I am obviously overlooking a bug in my code.  But as I said, I am more interested in why clang is not showing any warnings with `%zu`.